# How can I see 4 Composable Quadrants on the Android Studio preview pane? Android Basics with compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Why can I only see half of the Compose quadrant? Like this:
[My preview pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ood3m.png)

And not like this ?
[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1U8G.png)

I've been at this for days now I'm new to this so if someone could explain it to me like a 4 year old that would be great my code seems fine but apparently it isn't.

I tried all sorts of ways but it still does not change for some reason and the "solution" on GitHub doesn't really explain much. If someone could help out that would be great.

```
package com.example.composequadrant

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.composequadrant.ui.theme.ComposeQuadrantTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposeQuadrantTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ComposeQuadrant(head: String, body: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .fillMaxHeight(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        Text(
            text = head,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp),
        )
        Text(
            text = body,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ComposeQuadrants() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Row(Modifier.weight(1F)) {
            ComposeQuadrant(
                head = "Text composable",
                body = "Displays text and follows Material Design guidelines.",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFFEADDFF))
            )
            ComposeQuadrant(
                head = "Image composable",
                body = "Creates a composable that lays out and draws a given Painter class object.",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFFD0BCFF))
            )
        }
        Row(Modifier.weight(1F)) {
            ComposeQuadrant(
                head = "Row composable",
                body = "A layout composable that places its children in a horizontal sequence.",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFFB69DF8))
            )
            ComposeQuadrant(
                head = "Column composable",
                body = "A layout composable that places its children in a vertical sequence.",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFFF6EDFF))
            )
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ComposeQuadrantPreview() {
    ComposeQuadrantTheme {
        ComposeQuadrants()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with the fun **ComposeQuadrant** have a modifier passed to it as a parameter but you are not using it inside the function and if you are using android studio it will give you a **warning** that the value modifier is not used anywhere in the function and that is why you modifier that you pass to your function in **ComposeQuadrants** is not applied at all.
this is the corrected code:

```
    @Composable
    fun ComposeQuadrant(head: String, body: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
        Column(
            modifier = modifier,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            Text(
                text = head,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp),
            )
            Text(
                text = body,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
            )
        }
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun ComposeQuadrants() {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Row(Modifier.weight(1F)) {
                ComposeQuadrant(
                    head = "Text composable",
                    body = "Displays text and follows Material Design guidelines.",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .weight(1f)
                        .background(color = Color(0xFFEADDFF))
                        .padding(16.dp)
                )
                ComposeQuadrant(
                    head = "Image composable",
                    body = "Creates a composable that lays out and draws a given Painter class object.",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .weight(1f)
                        .background(color = Color(0xFFD0BCFF))
                        .padding(16.dp)
                )
            }
            Row(Modifier.weight(1F)) {
                ComposeQuadrant(
                    head = "Row composable",
                    body = "A layout composable that places its children in a horizontal sequence.",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .weight(1f)
                        .background(color = Color(0xFFB69DF8))
                        .padding(16.dp)
                )
                ComposeQuadrant(
                    head = "Column composable",
                    body = "A layout composable that places its children in a vertical sequence.",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .weight(1f)
                        .background(color = Color(0xFFF6EDFF))
                        .padding(16.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

**Warning: the padding modifier has to be used after the background modifier in order to acheive the desired UI provided by you. to understand why see [the importance of modifiers order](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers#order-modifier-matters)**

Comment: Hey man thank you so much for the response if I could I would like to personally thank you I can now move on with my life. To be honest I actually did wonder why I had a modifier parameter but it was never passed in anywhere but thank you so much for your detailed explanation I can now confidently move onto the next part of the course once again thank you !!

Comment: @omar4757 I'm glad to help anytime man I've been in your place once and people helped me so now I'm just returning the favor