# Jetpack Compose - Row not showing 2nd element

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I just started to learn Kotlin and Jetpack Compose using Androids developer pathways.

Currently I am stuck on a practice as my Row-Composable doesn't seem to work as it should as the 2nd elements in the row are not shown. All I get is a column with 2 entries (Top left and Bot left).

The result should look like this [Android Developer Composables Practice](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-composables-practice-problems?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-1-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-composables-practice-problems#3)

I compared my code to the solution code provided multiple times but can't find the difference which is causing this problem - hope you can help me.

```
@Composable
fun ComposeQuadrantApp()
{
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Row(Modifier.weight(1f)
        )
        {
            //Top left
            ComposableInfoCard(
                title = stringResource(R.string.topleft_title),
                description = stringResource(R.string.topleft_description),
                backgroundColor = Color(0xFFEADDFF),
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            //Top right
            ComposableInfoCard(
                title = stringResource(R.string.topright_title),
                description = stringResource(R.string.topright_description),
                backgroundColor = Color(0xFFD0BCFF),
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
        }

        Row(
            Modifier.weight(1f)
        ){
            //Bot left
            ComposableInfoCard(
                title = stringResource(R.string.botleft_title),
                description = stringResource(R.string.botleft_description),
                backgroundColor = Color(0xFFB69DF8),
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            //Bot right
            ComposableInfoCard(
                title = stringResource(R.string.botright_title),
                description = stringResource(R.string.botright_description),
                backgroundColor = Color(0xFFF6EDFF),
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
        }
    }
}


@Composable
private fun ComposableInfoCard(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    title: String,
    description: String,
    backgroundColor: Color) {

    Column (
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .padding(16.dp)
        ){
            Text(
                text = title,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp))
            Text(
                text = description,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Justify)
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

*I found the problem. The argument in the Column Composable in my ComposableInfoCard function should be modifier = **m**odifier.fillMaxSize()... instead of a capital written "**M**odifier".
Could someone explain why this leads to the mentioned problem?
I think I don't understand the modifier correctly yet..*

Comment: I was just about to write the answer as you edited the question, but what you need to know, is that when you typed ``Modifier`` (in the Column inside ``ComposableInfoCard``)  you created a fresh modifier and applied the adjustments, in stand of using the modifier that you passed and adding adjustments on top of that (in android studio, you can clearly see that the parameter ``modifier`` wasn't in use in ``ComposableInfoCard``).

Comment: I have already answer the same question to another person about the same thing you can see it here with the explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/76469507/19954200

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is about your **ComposableInfoCard**. You did set weight to it but you dont use it.
Here is my change for you:

```
@Composable
private fun ComposableInfoCard(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    title: String,
    description: String,
    backgroundColor: Color
) {

Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .background(backgroundColor)
        .padding(16.dp)
) {
    Text(
        text = title,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp)
    )
    Text(
        text = description,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
    )
}
}
```

Happy Coding.....